# PHP to delete cookie in php class

Tags: php, cookies, header

I am about to control my pages content. so that I need add or delete sessions/cookies. I maked a class that is working fine but in the cookie issue, it is not working as well. I checked with firefox 18 in windows7, and ubuntu 12.04 LTS. the cookies are not deleted using

```
        setcookie(name, '', time()-9600) 



        foreach($this->_ck as $cookie)
        {

        $hrs=0;
            if($plus)
            {
        $hrs=3600*$cfg_cookie_time;
            }
            //setcookie('testcookie13', '', time()-3600*6);

        header("Set-Cookie: ".$cookie."=deleted; expires=Sun, 01-Jul-2012 08:59:12 GMT;");
        }
```

etc...

My class is:

```
<?php

class headers{
    var $new;
    var $vars;
    var $ss;
    var $ck;
    var $_ss;
    var $_ck;
    var $error;
    var $catchs;

    function _construct()
    {
        $this->new=false;
        $this->error=false;
        $this->ss=array();
        $this->ck=array();
        $this->_ss=array();
        $this->_ck=array();
        $this->catchs=true;
    return $this->catchs;
    } //f
    function headers($hs = array(
    "set" => array(
        "ss" => array(),
        "ck" => array()
        )
    ))
    {

    if(isset($hs['send']))
    {
    $this->new=$hs['send'];
    $this->catchs=true;
    }
    if(is_array($hs['set']))
    {

        if(is_array($hs['set']['ss']))
        {
        $this->ss = $hs['set']['ss'];
        }

        if(is_array($hs['set']['ck']))
        {
        $this->ck = $hs['set']['ck'];
        }
    }
    if(is_array($hs['unset']))
    {

        if($hs['unset']['ss'])
        {
        $this->_ss = $hs['unset']['ss'];
        }

        if(is_array($hs['unset']['ck']))
        {
        $this->_ck = $hs['unset']['ck'];
        }
    }
    return $this->catchs;
    } //f

    function send(
    $cfg_cookie_time=6,
    $plus=true
    )
    {
    $cookie='';
        if(is_array($this->ss))
        {
            session_start();
            foreach($this->ss as $session){
            $_SESSION['session'] = $session;
            }
        }

        if($this->_ck)
        {
foreach ($_COOKIE as $name => $value) {
    setcookie($name, '', 1);
}
        }
        if($this->ck)
        {
            foreach($this->ck as $cookie => $val)
            {

            //$this->ck=$cookie.$val;
            $hrs=0;
                if($plus)
                {
            $hrs=3600*$cfg_cookie_time;
                }
            header("Set-Cookie: ".$cookie."=".$val."; path=/; domain=".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."; expires=".gmstrftime("%A, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S GMT;", time()+$hrs));
            }
        }

        if($this->new)
        {
        header("location: ".$this->new);
        $this->catchs=false;
        }

        header("X-Powered-By: PHP ".phpversion()."/FxPHP");

        //header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");

    return $this->ck;

    } //f

} // class

            setcookie('H',  '',  -3600);

/*$hr = new HEADERS( array
(

    "set" => array
    (
        "ck"=> array(),
        "ss"=> array() 
    ),
    "unset" => array
    (
        "ck"=> array
        (
        "H" => "H"
        ),
        "ss"=> array() 
    )
)

    );
print_r( $_COOKIE).print_r($hr->send());

/*
             " f" => "" ,
             " sf" => "",
            "my"=> "" ,

print_r(getallheaders());
print_r(setcookie('sd', 'dsds', 3600*6));
*/

?>
```

Can you any help?

Comment: Try using `setcookie(cookie, null);` if that doesn't work then it's something in your conditions

Comment: I've tried. but not delete any cookie. 
setcookie('H', null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
<?php


function del_cookie($_cookie = array())
{
    foreach($_cookie as $k => $kv)
        {
        setcookie($k, '', time()-3600);
        }
        return;
}


function add_cookie($_cookie)
{
        foreach($_cookie as $k => $kv)
        {
        setcookie($k, $kv, time()+3600*24*6);
        }
        return;
}


class headers{
    var $new;
    var $vars;
    var $ss;
    var $ck;
    var $_ss;
    var $_ck;
    var $_ak;
    var $_dk;
    var $error;
    var $catchs;

    function _constract()
    {
        $this->new=false;
        $this->error=false;
        $this->ss=array();
        $this->ck=array();
        $this->_ss=array();
        $this->_ck=array();
        $this->catchs=true;             
        $this->_ak = false;             
        $this->_dk = false;
    return $this->catchs;
    } //f
    function headers($hs = array(
    "set" => array(
        "ss" => array(),
        "ck" => array()
        )
    ))
    {

    if(isset($hs['send']))
    {
    $this->new=$hs['send'];
    $this->catchs=true;
    }
    if($hs['set']['ck']['true'])
    {
    $this->ck = $hs['set']['ck'];               
    $this->_ak = true;
    }

        /*if($hs['unset']['ss'])
        {
        $this->_ss = $hs['unset']['ss'];
        }
        */
    if($hs['unset']['ck']['true'])
    {
        $this->_ck = $hs['unset']['ck'];        
        $this->_dk = true;      

    }
    return $this->catchs;
    } //f

    function send(
    $cfg_cookie_time=6,
    $plus=true
    )
    {
        if(is_array($this->ss))
        {
            session_start();
            foreach($this->ss as $session){
            $_SESSION['session'] = $session;
            }
        }

        if($this->_dk)
        {
del_cookie($this->_ck);
        }
        if($this->_ak)
        {
add_cookie($this->ck);
        }

        if($this->new)
        {
        header("location: ".$this->new);
        $this->catchs=false;
        }

        header("X-Powered-By: PHP ".phpversion()."/FxPHP");

        //header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");

    return $this->catchs;

    } //f

} // class
$hr = new HEADERS( array
(

    "set" => array
    (
        "ck"=> array(
        "true" => ""
        ),
        "ss"=> array
        (
        "true" => "") 
    ),
    "unset" => array
    (
        "ck"=> array
        (
        "true" => "YES",
        "Test" => "1"
        ),
        "ss"=> array
        (
        "true" => "") 
    )
)

    );


print_r( $_COOKIE).print_r($hr->send());

/*
             " f" => "" ,
             " sf" => "",
            "my"=> "" ,

print_r(getallheaders());
print_r(setcookie('sd', 'dsds', 3600*6));
*/

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One error I see in your code is

```
    function _constract()
```

which should be

```
    function __construct()
```

Comment: Yeh!! but without the class. I checked with setcookie(name, '', time()-9600). It is not working. Cookies are saved in browser. but not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie($cookie_name, null, null);
```

Will delete a cookie no matter what. Use that in plain php in the beginning of a script before any logic to verify that. If you're using this and your cookies are not being deleted you're either using xml requests or you have some issues in your logic. Good luck!